# Symfony: How can I get full country name

Tags: php, symfony

I am using the `CountryType` field in `Symfony`. It now is displaying the country initials like *NL* for *Netherlands*. But I want to display the full country name.

How can I display the full country name instead of only country initials?

Code is as follows :

```
use Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl;
...

$countries = Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryNames();

$builder->add('companyaddresscountry', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => $countries, 'label'=>'Country'));
```

Comment: Describe better where is your problem and add all the related code. Tip: you should store the country code in the DB instead of the translated name. Tip: to show the country list (in a dropdown) using the INTL component just flip the array to display their names instead of their codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your choices are not ['as values'](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices-as-values). You can either flip your array using php's function [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

```
$countries = Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryNames();

$builder->add('companyaddresscountry', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array_flip($countries),
    'label'=>'Country'
));
```

or add parameter to your form field 'choices_as_values' (this option is deprecated):

> This option is deprecated and you should remove it from your 3.x projects (removing it will have no effect). For its purpose in 2.x, see the 2.7 documentation.

```
$countries = Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryNames();

$builder->add('companyaddresscountry', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => $countries,
    'label'=>'Country',
    'choices_as_values' => true
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside array $countries you could have an array where the key is only 2 letters but the value is the full name like this:

```
$countries
```

equals to

```
array('AF' => 'Afghanistan', ...)
```

So you can parse your array and get only values for the full name

```
$fullname = [];
foreach ($countries as $key => $value) {
    $fullname[] = $value;
}
```